# VBA ADO connection string with Encryption

Tags: sql-server, vba, ado

I have a remote database (SQL Server) that I connect to via the Internet.

I use this connection string (works perfectly):

```
ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};" _
                            & "Server=xxx.xxx.x.xx;" _
                            & "Database=MyDbName;" _
                            & "Uid=MyId;" _
                            & "Pwd={MyPassword};" _
                            & "Connection Timeout=30;"
```

I was asked to add encryption to this connection string, but I do not know what I am required to add and where...

I tried to add this `Encrypt=yes;` commend to the connection string but I get an error (“The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted”).

Server OS - Windows server 2016 standard.

Users OS - windows 7 - 10 with Excel 2007 - 2019 or 365

Comment: Give this a look
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: What error do you get?  What is your client OS?  The Server's OS?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - I updated my post

Comment: When SQL Server gets installed a self-signed X.509 certificate is used by default, so won't be trusted by any CA-related certificates in your Trusted Roots store. When adding `Encrypt=yes` to your connection string you probably also need to include `TrustServerCertificate=yes` as well.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - I add `"Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;"` to the connection string and it works, is this mean that now my connection string is encrypted and more secure ?

Comment: It means your connection is encrypted, but personally I wouldn't consider it more secure. `TrustServerCertificate=yes` basically tells the client to trust any X.509 certificate that's provided, whether any of its `Subject` or `DnsAlt` names match the FQDN or IP address used to connect or not, so this theoretically allows Man-in-the-Middle impersonation attacks where someone could route your traffic to an SQL Server of their own choosing.

Comment: In our own SQL Server environments we either deploy certificates signed by our internal CA (Certificate Authority) or export the public key portion of self-signed certificate from the SQL Server to import into the Trusted Root stores of the necessary client(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server doesn't have a certificate that the client trusts, then you can't create an encrypted connection without explicitly approving the untrusted certificate with the `TrustServerCertificate` connection string keyword.

See: [Using Encryption Without Validation in SQL Server Native Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-encryption-without-validation?view=sql-server-ver15)